# reactjs: useEffect: how to handle large data with smooth transition

Tags: reactjs

I am using `"react": "17.0.2"`,
I am rendering a large table.

#### scenario one (loading data directly without any delay)

```
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      setTableData([...large data]);
  });
  
 return(
  <MaterialReactTable
    columns={[ .. columns List]}
    data={tableData}
  />
 )
```

#### Scenario 2: loading with some delay

```
  const columns = [..columnslist]
  const stateTable = useCustomHook()  <-- custom hook
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setTableData(stateTable.recentSmsDataRed);
    }, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  },);
  
 return(
  <MaterialReactTable
    columns={[ .. columns List]}
    data={tableData}
  />
 )
```

I found scenario 2 is more smoother (alteast it first shows a empty table).

Scenario 1 is making the parent component also stuck and no table ui is shown unless its loaded fully.

whats the practise

Comment: Try to use <Suspense> API of reactjs

Comment: What is the practice in what specifically, what do you wan't to achieve? do you want to add loading indicator in the table section when the data is loading?

Comment: I am using `"react": "17.0.2"`. will it work with this

Comment: @Amr  the data is static but huge. but if loaded without timeout, this component shows blank till it loads the entire table.   If using timeout, first we can see a blank table and then it appears data is filled.

Comment: @Amr  i could have direclty pass the static data to the table, but i found using useeffect, we can load data once ui is rendered

Comment: If the data is static, you could add loading indicator in the table section to the data value when it is `undefined`